# What's the meaning of "wider community" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

***The sports centre is available to both the university and **the wider community.***

—From Longman dictionary

I think it means-

*1)A large number of groups of people having similar interest, belief etc....*

Are there any other way possible to interpret this sentence??

Comment: Close to the physical meaning of broader, wider than the school campus and spilling over to the surrounding town. That's all.

Comment: @YosefBaskin what I said conveys the same idea or not??

Comment: Not really. Not people with similarities, just living nearby. The sports centre is available to both the school (students, teachers, other employees) and anyone who can travel there for an athletic event (in the wider community of folks within an hour).

Comment: It probably means any outside group (within reason) can book it.

Comment: @Peter yes, I think that it involves a large variety of different groups.

Comment: @Peter It could also implies *spread among a large number of groups*

Comment: "The wider community" may well _include_ different groups, but the _meaning_ is just "local people who are not connected with the university".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the context should give you a big clue. "... to both the university and the wider community". So "the wider community" is contrasted with "the university".

It means "people not part of the previously mentioned group or groups". In this case, people not part of the university.

One might also say, for example, "... the employees of XYZ Corporation and also the wider community", meaning the employees and also people who are not employees. Or, "... Hindus and the wider community", meaning Hindus and non-Hindus. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

**wider community** there refers to people unaffiliated with the university and living in the *vicinity* of the university, however that is defined by the university: in the same town, perhaps, or in certain neighborhoods abutting the university campus, and so on.

Comment: People who are not in the vicinity of the university can't come?

Comment: The sports center would not be available for use to everyone; the university would limit access in some way.  What is referred to is not only where sports are played, like a basketball arena, but to exercise areas, indoor running tracks, weight lifting rooms, etc. They are usually not "open to the general public", to anyone, anywhere, but to "neighboring" communities.

Comment: And often the neighboring communities have access only on certain days and during certain hours.